# Is local video streaming site possible?

Tags: linux, video, streaming-video

I'm not familiar with Raspberry Pi and I just want to ask if my idea is possible.

I am planning to install Ubuntu and Python 3. I will put all videos in a hard drive, connect it to the Raspberry Pi, and on the directory of videos I will run `python -m http.server`.

If you open `http://localhost:8000/` in the browser it should list all the videos in the current directory, but instead of `localhost`, I will use the local network address `192.168.254.XXX` to access it on other devices on the same network (smart TV, laptop, PC, phone).

Then I will select a file there and it should play the video on the browser used by the other devices.

Do you think this is possible?

If it is possible, how many devices watching different videos at the same time this can handle?

Comment: Why not use something like KODI https://kodi.tv it's free and does a whole let better than browsing folders...

Comment: I don't want the videos to be put on the cloud, just local copy as some may contain copyrights (eg. pirated movies)

Comment: Run kodi locally with local storage...

Comment: I see I will look also into that possibility thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you think this is possible?

Yes.

> If it is possible, how many devices watching different videos at the same time this can handle?

This is dependent on the bandwidth required by each stream (and what kind of compression is used), and on the exact nature of the network -- eg., if the Pi is its own hotspot, that is probabaly a bit more efficient than if it and the clients are on a WLAN and communicate via a router -- but I would not expect more than 3-4.  And that will probably not be in HD.